# ajax post to php is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to make an AJAX post to php but for some reason my PHP says that the post is empty. I don't get an error message from PHP or in my console. The `alert(data)` at the end returns all the HTML in `index.php` and the `var_dump(post)` returns empty. [image: console.log] first is the console.log(aantal) the second is console.log(data)
[image]End of the console.log

*script.js*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var date = "date";
    var begin = "begin";
    var eind = "eind";
    var aantal = "aantal";


    $('#datum').change(function () {
        date = $("#datum").val();
        console.log(date);
    });
    $('#beginTijd').change(function () {
        begin = ($(this).val());
        console.log(begin);
    });
    $('#Tijdsduur').change(function () {
        eind = ($(this).val());
        console.log(eind);
    });
    $('#aantalSloepen').change(function () {
        aantal = ($(this).val());
        console.log(aantal);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {
                date: begin,
                quantity: aantal
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$value1 = "";
$value2 = "";
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    echo "Yes, mail is set";
    $value1 = $_POST['date'];
    $value2 = $_POST['quantity'];
} else {
    echo "No, mail is not set";
}
echo $value1;
echo $value2;
```

Comment: What is `aantalSloepen` ? And what `console.log(aantal)`  Returns ?

Comment: if i remember correctly that should be method: "post" and not type

Comment: `type` is fine.

Comment: aantal sloepen is a select

Comment: @moveax  no it's correct

Comment: What `console.log(aantal)` Returns @berto

Comment: are `script.js` file and `index.php` files in the same location?

Comment: that returns the number you selected in the select. 1-6

Comment: yes they are in the same directory @PankajMakwana

Comment: have you tried enabling error reporting ?`error_reporting(-1)`

Comment: If I put that at the top of my php I still don't get errors

Comment: put your console screenshot

Comment: I have added the image to the post

Comment: the script you are adding is in `index.php` file?

Comment: yes is that what is causing the problem?

Comment: so if you are calling `index.php` from ajax and the files you have loaded is `index.php` so whole file will be called and it will return whole page's html.

Comment: @berto, I have posted an answer check if it helps

Comment: If I use your example it returns nothing not echo "Yes, mail is set"; and not  echo "No, mail is not set";

Comment: Check your screenshot at the end you will get the values printed. To work properly you have to move php code before the html code start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `index.php` file from the ajax and the index.php file is loaded on page load. So when you call the ajax it will return whole html code of `index.php` to prevent that you have to add `exit()` function to prevent execute further. See code below.

```
<?php

$value1 = "";
$value2 = "";
if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
        echo "Yes, mail is set";
        $value1 = $_POST['date'];
        $value2 = $_POST['quantity'];
    } else {
        echo "No, mail is not set";
    }
    exit;
}

<html>
    <!-- Your Code goes here -->
</html>
```

Comment: I replaced my php with yours but now it returns nothing it does not echo yes,mail is set but also not no, mail is not set

Comment: shouldn't it be exit();?

Comment: I don't k'now but it does't make a differece it still returns nothing @LelioFaieta

Comment: do you get anything in the $_POST ? print_r($_POST); exit;

Comment: show your console after ajax call https://imagebin.ca/v/3wKHfG5IOK2Y like this url

Comment: I get  a empty array "Array ( )" @MartinS.

Comment: I added the picture in the post

Comment: put your php code before the html code then it will work

Comment: Checkout your screenshot from this link. You have got the response.
https://imagebin.ca/v/3wKKudgTKxIv

Comment: Now it shows this in the alert. But the php does not echo "yes, mail is set or "No, mail is not set".
Array
(
    [date] => begin
    [quantity] => 2
)
Yes, mail is set

Comment: I did move it to the top but the php does not echo yes or no. the console.log now shows the data that needs to be send

Comment: the php echo's in my console.log or something like that because if I change the echo "yes, mail is set" the return in console.log also changes @PankajMakwana